# An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused SYMFONY 4

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I Just changed my computer(macosx) and then, i'm trying to work on my project again.

I'm trying to create the database and I'm having an error :

" An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused  "

I tried to change the server versions , to make new account on mySQL, to change the ports ( 3336 instead of 8889) and to had new line that I found on stack and other sites posts.

Here is my .env

```
APP_ENV=dev
APP_SECRET=959a3e56d7f63b190f107a24fc7eade4
#TRUSTED_PROXIES=127.0.0.0/8,10.0.0.0/8,172.16.0.0/12,192.168.0.0/16
#TRUSTED_HOSTS='^localhost|example\.com$'
###< symfony/framework-bundle ###

###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
# Format described at https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#connecting-using-a-url
# For an SQLite database, use: "sqlite:///%kernel.project_dir%/var/data.db"
# For a PostgreSQL database, use: "postgresql://db_user:db_password@127.0.0.1:5432/db_name?serverVersion=11&charset=utf8"
# IMPORTANT: You MUST configure your server version, either here or in config/packages/doctrine.yaml
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:@127.0.0.1:8889/mysuper?serverVersion=5.7
###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###

###> nelmio/cors-bundle ###
CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN=^https?://(localhost|127\.0\.0\.1)(:[0-9]+)?$
###< nelmio/cors-bundle ###
```

and here is my config.yaml

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver: 'pdo_mysql'
        server_version: '5.7'
        charset: utf8mb4
        default_table_options:
          charset: utf8mb4
          collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'

        # IMPORTANT: You MUST configure your server version,
        # either here or in the DATABASE_URL env var (see .env file)
        #server_version: '5.7'
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                type: annotation
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
                alias: App
```

I'm on it since 4 hours and I'm cracking a bottle n thanx by advance

Comment: Are you sure that env exist? Did you tried echo $DATABASE_URL in project directory?

Comment: And why you have `:` after root?

Comment: @UrmatZhenaliev That's the equivalent of root without password (it's `username:password`, but the password is an empty string).